# Is there any way to pass headerField parameter in SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to pass parameter in header of SafariViewController like access_token, id_token for logged In user.
users already logged via a native app

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't use SFSafariViewController. Use ASWebAuthenticationSession or SFAuthenticationSession for login.
2. Regarding OAuth docs, these parameters are transferred by query parameters.
3. The cookies are shared between these apps.
4. The best approach is to relog in automatically when a user tries to log in to the app.
5. Headers are not transferred to those classes.